# Bit complexity of modulo operations?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms

We know that using FFT we can compute multiplication of an $a$ bit number with a $b$ bit number in $(a+b)^{1+\epsilon}$ time.

My question is supposing we want to compute $A\bmod B$ where $A$ is an $a=f(b)$ bit number for some linear function of $b$ with $B$ a $b$ bit number, what is the time and space complexity of such an operation? Could it be done in fully linear ($O(a+b)$) time and space complexity (at least assuming $B$ is fixed per $b$ bits and $A$ is input)? I have been unable to find such a reference or procedure for this operation even when $B$ is fixed (which is the case useful in operations such as Diffie Hellman key exchange).

Comment: When $B$ is fixed, $A\bmod B$ is computable by a finite automaton, hence in space $O(1)$ and time $O(a)$.

Comment: Interesting, could you please describe the algorithm? Also is this what is used in crypto?

Comment: If I understand Emil's suggestion correctly, then it uses space $\: \Theta \hspace{.02 in}(b) \:$ and time $\: \Theta \hspace{.02 in}(a\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}b) \;$. $\hspace{.68 in}$ ($\hspace{.02 in}$When $B$ is fixed, that gives what he wrote.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I see then I have not explained well. Hope this explains better.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek corrected the question ($B$ is fixed per $b$ bits).

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you mean When you say $B$ is fixed per $b$ bits. Here's how I understand what you are saying:

There exists a sequence $B_1, B_2, ...$ where $B_i$ has $i$ bits. There exists a linear function $f$. The problem takes as input integer $A$ with $a$ bits; let $b = f^{-1}(a)$ such that $a = f(b)$. The task is to output $A \mod B_b$. Is that right?

Because if that's what you mean, you could have a problem if the sequence $B_1, B_2, ...$ is not computable.

Comment: Perhaps he would be OK with a preprocessing model: you give me a $b$-bit $B$. I run some algorithm for $poly(B)$ steps, creating some data structure of $O(B)$ size. Finally you give me any $A$ of $O(B)$ bits and I can compute $A ~mod~ B$  in $O(B)$ time, using the data stucture.